# Corollay of Theorem 4.1.3 from Arveson's Book

Tags: operator-theory

from book A Short Course on Spectral Theory , William Arveson

Corollary of Theorem 4.1.3 says

> Every Toeplitz operator $T_\phi,\phi \in L^\infty$, satisfies
>
> $\displaystyle\inf\{\|T_{\phi}+K\| \colon K\in \mathcal{K} \}=\|T_{\phi}\|=\|\phi\|_\infty.$

if $P_n=S^n S^{*n}$. don't know how deduce

> $\|P_n(A+K)P_n\|=\|S^{*n}(A+K)S^n\|$

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift $S$ is an isometry; algebraically, that's $S^*S=I$. So, for any $T$, 
$$
\|ST\|^2=\|T^*S^*ST\|=\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2.
$$
And 
$$
\|TS^*\|^2=\|TS^*ST^*\|=\|TT^*\|=\|T^*\|^2=\|T\|^2.
$$
Now apply each $n$ times.

Comment: thanks, but why the equal $\|TS^*\|^2=\|TS^*ST^*\|$

Comment: Because $\|TS^*\|=\|ST^*\|$.

Comment: and another cuestion, when in this corollay he say $P_{n}\downarrow 0$, it means $\|P_{n}\|\rightarrow 0$ convergence in norm? thanks

Comment: No, that makes no sense since $P_n$ are projections and so $\|P_n\|=1$ for all $n$. The meaning of $P_n\searrow0$ is that the sequence is decreasing and the infimum is zero. It's equivalent with $P_nx\to0$ for all $x$.

Comment: oh yes, i forgot these, thanks